# Resource leak warning and line breakpoint in eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

Simple program to get array elements.
I get both the message at line 5

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Hier {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr=new int[4];
        int i;
        
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=inp.nextInt();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Elements: ");
        
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be more precise about the line number. We are confused about which one is it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to close a `Scanner` – except when it wraps `System.in` because you should not close the standard input. Eclipse is not clever enough to know the difference and that's why it gives you a warning. You can safely ignore the warning, or you can use the *SuppressWarnings* annotation.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Hier {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("inp")
        Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr=new int[4];
        int i;
        
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=inp.nextInt();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Elements: ");
        
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.in` can be changed via `System.setIn​(...)`, so there is no guarantee that `System.in` does not need to be closed.

Answer (score -1):

You basically need to close your scanner once you are done using it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            int[] arr = new int[4];
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = inp.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Elements: ");

            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        } finally
        {
            inp.close();
        }
    }
```

Or if using Java 7+, you can use try-with-resources like this:

```
try (Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in)) 
{
//your code
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is just wrong here, and this is therefore bad advice. What needs actual closing is _actual_ resources. `Scanner`, just like `BufferedInputStream` and co are filterstreams - they wrap an actual resource. They aren't themselves things that need closing. It's normally smart to close them: They could buffer, and closing has a built in flush (and will also close the thing they wrap). The key clue here is that the thing it wraps (`System.in`) was __not__ created by this code and therefore should __not__ be closed by this code, either. Eclipse should not warn about filterstreams.

Comment: With that background in mind: You don't want to close System.in (there are exotic cases where you do, but it's definitely not the appropriate thing in most circumstances, and this question is all about general advice, not a specific situation). closing the scanner will close System.in.